# Looking for simple/easy PHP-based Feed Parser

Tags: php, rss, feed, atom-feed

i am looking for a simple implementation of an PHP-based feed parser. it doesn't have to be extremely robust, flexible, or fast. easy setup and use is more important, it's for a student assignment. the goal is to consume feeds, and to wrap entries and their fields into simple HTML structures. ease of use really is the most important issue. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[MagpieRSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) seems to be popular - and simple.